# How to bind an jQuery onclick event with Coffeescript, in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I realise that I probably need to declare the onclick event globally, but I am trying to avoid using the `--bare` tag when compiling.

This is the code I am trying to get working...

```
jQuery ->
  $('.tabs_image').click ->
    $(this).addClass('tabs_selected')
    $('.tabs_video').removeClass('tabs_selected')
    $('#image_upload_form').show()
    $('#video_upload_form').hide()
    return

  $('.tabs_video').click ->
    $(this).addClass('tabs_selected')
    $('.tabs_image').removeClass('tabs_selected')
    $('#image_upload_form').hide()
    $('#video_upload_form').show()
    return

  return
```

It works fine once the page is hard refreshed (refresh clicked) in the browser Chrome.

I have tried `$ =>`, `$(document).ready ->`, and `$(document).ready =>`.

Comment: "*It works fine once the page has refreshed in the browser Chrome.*" If the content is dynamic appended, [you'll have to use delegated events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski In this case the content already exists; it is not dynamically appended. I will try that though. This is in a Rails app, so I do not know if that would have an effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I found the crux of the problem - My Coffeescript was fine, it was
>   because of a gem called [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) that the code was not
>   triggering. It keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only
>   the body and the title in the head, which means you can't rely on
>   `DOMContentLoaded` or `jQuery.ready()` to trigger your code. This is
>   why the script would seem to work when the page was hard refreshed
>   (refresh clicked).

### For those who use Turbolinks

- **If you want to opt out specific links**

Add `data-no-turbolink` to the parent container of the link(s) like so...

```
<a href="/">Home (via Turbolinks)</a>
<div id="some-div" data-no-turbolink>
  <a href="/">Home (without Turbolinks)</a>
</div>
```

- **If you have a lot of existing JavaScript that binds elements on `jQuery.ready()`**

Using the event hook `page:change`, you can replace the `jQuery.ready()` with `$(document).on 'page:change', ->` or, even better `$(document).on 'ready page:change', ->`; better, because it means that even if turbolinks is not running (because of being on an old browser version maybe), the call will still trigger due to `ready` being there.

> It is best to use `page:change` instead of `page:load`. The former event hook fires when the page is loaded from the server or from the client-side cache, whereas the latter event hook only fires when a new body element has been loaded into the DOM ([source](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events)).

...**or**...

You can use the [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

`bundle install` and then add it to your JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd argue that you should be using event delegation anyway.

Try something like this and see if you get better results:

```
$ ->
  $('body').on 'click', '.tabs_image', ->
    # do stuff
```

Comment: *"I'd argue that you should be using event delegation anyway."* Why, given that *"In this case the content already exists; it is not dynamically appended."*

Comment: @nick Thank you, I have tried this, but does not help. I am getting the feeling I have found a bug in Rails

Comment: Now that I know it was because of [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), using the hook `page:load` works by replacing your `$ ->` with `$(document).on 'page:load', ->` or `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->`

Comment: @KevinB because if there are multiple matching selectors, you are attaching the same event multiple times. It could result in memory leaks. Probably edge case for most apps, but there's nothing wrong with just using event delegation in general to combat these potential challenges. PPK touches on it here in the sentence just before "The focus problem": http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

Answer (score 0):

load the dom with `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->` instead of `jQuery ->` you can read more on the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks)

Comment: It is best to use `page:change` than `page:load` ([source](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events))